# split up a radForm into multiple files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, telerik

I have tried multiple ways to do this.
I have a Telerik Radform, it has a tabbed interface.
Due to that the code is getting largeish, around 3,000 lines.

I would like to have a separate file for each of the tabs - there are currently 5 different tabs.

I have tried using a partial class inheriting from my main form by:

- step 1 - created a blank code file.
- step 2 - put my namespace and create a partial class from my main form.
- step 3 - move a button click event from my main form file to my new file

The code runs, but if I double click the button in the designer it takes me back to the spot where the code used to be - the RadForm1.cs file not the StopCreation_code.cs file.

Here is my namespace and class from my main file:

```
namespace Flex_EDI_Console
{
    public partial class RadForm1 : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
    {
```

and here is my new file and the button click event I moved:

```
namespace Flex_EDI_Console

{
    public partial class RadForm1
    {
        private void radButton31_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Flex_EDI_Console.stop_details newStop = new Flex_EDI_Console.stop_details();

            DateTime shipDateToSearch = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/2017");

            //this.radDataEntry1.DataSource = newStop;
            var consingeeList = (from c in dbContext.stop_details where c.ship_date > shipDateToSearch select c.con_name).ToArray().Distinct();

            this.consignee_name_DD.DataSource = consingeeList;
            this.consignee_name_DD.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            this.consignee_name_DD.DropDownListElement.AutoCompleteSuggest.SuggestMode = Telerik.WinControls.UI.SuggestMode.Contains;

            consignee_lb.Text = "Consignee - found " + consingeeList.Count();

        }
    }
 }
```

Also, the CodeCreation_code.cs opens up a form designer.

Thank you for any advice....I used to use regions for this but I am trying to stay away from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think the Form Designer supports this kind of the scenario. Take a look at the following statement from MSDN forum.

> The Windows Forms Designer does not support dividing a designable
>   type's definition into more than two partial implementations. This
>   restriction includes creating a new class file that contains a third
>   partial definition of the type, as well as adding a third partial
>   class definition of the type in either the main file or the designer
>   file. Members defined this way will not be visible in the Windows
>   Forms Designer. See
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171843.aspx
>
> This is by design and I don't think you the Windows Forms Designer
>   will work with your secondary partial class.

And we know that the RadForm control is an extension of the standard Windows Form. So its Form Designer would not support that either.

However, you should be able to use the navigation options or relevant keyboard shortcuts in VS to locate your partial class files.

Please refer to [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/79910eaa-84e7-472d-95ee-4b8ddfbf99f0/multiple-partial-class-files-cause-problems-with-forms-designer?forum=winforms) for more details.

Comment: Woodykiddy - I am afraid you may be right, I was hoping I was missing something.  Thank you for the link to the article, I am still working my way through it and will try some of it's suggestions.  With it being 4 years old I was thinking somebody may have a better workflow that what I am doing.